# how to implement Sensu Check for checking if Docker Container is running or not

Tags: docker, sensu

Hi i am trying to implement https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-docker/blob/master/bin/check-container.rb , in my sensu-client i have added the check-container.rb file and created a check in sensu-server with name sensu-check-jenkins-container

```
{    
    "checks":
     {    
        "sensu-check-jenkins-container":    
        {
            "command": "TOKEN_SENSU_CLIENT_DIR/plugins/basic/check-container.rb jenkins",    
            "handlers": ["mailer"],    
            "subscribers": ["sensu"],    
            "interval": 86400    
        }    
    }    
}
```

But when i try to restart the sensu-server and check i am getting error as the required client helpers not found in sensu-client , i had installed the following gem "gem install sensu-plugins-docker --pre" but it did not resolve the issue , can anyone help me resolve this issue . i am using hiroakis docker sensu server and client

Comment: Can you plase add the error message too? What is the 'TOKEN_SENSU_CLIENT_DIR' thing?

Comment: TOKEN_SENSU_DIR will point to /app/sensu/plugins. i am getting one issue regarding require 'sensu-plugins-docker/client_helpers' and also when i run  it says require cannot load such file -net_http_unix (Load Error) from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom.require.rb:36 in 'require'